# Is $\iint_D\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z} {(z-\zeta)^2} = 0$ true.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, differential-forms

I am reading [An elementary proof of the existence of isothermal parameters on a surface](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-05/S0002-9939-1955-0074856-1/S0002-9939-1955-0074856-1.pdf)

There is an integral in it

> $$\int_{D} \frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z}{z-\zeta} = - 2{\pi}i{\bar{\zeta}} $$ where $D$ is a disc of radius $R$ centered at origin and $\zeta$ is a point in $D$

I take $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$ on it

$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}(-2\pi i\bar{\zeta})=\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}(\int_{D} \frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z}{z-\zeta}) =\int_D\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z}{z-\zeta}=\int_D\frac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z} {(z-\zeta)^2}$$

but i don't know whether $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$ commute with $\int$

I try to compute it directly .i can write $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z} {(z-\zeta)^2} $ as $\mathrm{d}(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}}{z-\zeta})$ but it has singular point .i can't use stoke's theorem

Is $\iint_D\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\bar{z}\mathrm{d}z} {(z-\zeta)^2} = 0$ true??

thank you!!

Comment: Commuting $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$  with $\int$ needs that integrand and it's derivate be continuous.

Comment: Also $D$ must be simply connected (like here)

Comment: We should better understand $dz\,d\bar z$. Chern is making a hint to exterior algebra and takes it as $2i{\rm d}(x,y)$, where ${\rm d}(x,y)$ is just Lebesgue measure on $D$.

Comment: Won't the singularity at $z=\zeta$ now be too strong for the integral to converge?

Comment: Two comments: First of all, $dz\wedge d\bar z = -2idx\wedge dy$, so (in part) this is why Chern writes $d\bar z\wedge dz$ in his formulas. Second, I don't see anywhere in the paper that Chern considers the integral you're writing down. But the first formula you wrote down follows from the generalized Cauchy Integral Formula: $$\int_{\partial D} \frac{f(z)}{z-\zeta}\,dz = 2\pi i f(\zeta) + \int_D \frac{\partial f/\partial \bar z}{z-\zeta}\,d\bar z\wedge dz.$$ Anyhow, I don't think that integral converges ...

Comment: The problem with your derivation is that the integral at the end does not converge absolutely. It can be justified if you interpret it as a Cauchy principal value integral, though.

Comment: By the way, I think the easiest way to calculate the value of the integral is to write it in polar coordinates and use the residue theorem.